Typeorm JS how to manually create DeleteDateColumn?
I'm using Typeorm's new Table() and would like to create a delete_date column in a migration, the same as the @DeleteDateColumn decorator is doing. (will auto-filled once deleted, won't delete the row, and won't be returned when pulling from the table)
What should be the column's properties? (postgres db)

